# Find angle for UIPushBehavior with two CGPoints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, geometry, uikit-dynamics, uidynamicbehavior

I am working on a project involving iOS 7 UIDyanmics and and UIPushBehavior. As part of this I am trying to calculate the angle (expressed in radians) of an object based on two CGPoints. In my research I've found this answer but its expressed in Java.

[Find the Angle between two Bearings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180595/find-the-angle-between-two-bearings)

If someone has the Objective-C equivalent that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given two points...

```
#include <math.h>
CGPoint p0;
CGPoint p1;
```

The angle is the arctan of the quotient of the change in each dimension...

```
double dx = p0.x-p1.x;
double dy = p0.y-p1.y;

double angle = (dx)? atan(dy/dx) : NAN;
```

FYI, for next time, the SO culture strongly encourages questioners to show research, produce an attempt at a solution.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your code example and response. Since I posted this question I've been working through some math questions and have arrived at the same result.

Comment: Glad to hear.  The next step - if you deem the answer to be correct - is to mark it correct (by checking the little checkmark that appears at the upper left of this answer).